# Не работает сборка проекта gulp 4 при помощи вызова таска Build

Tags: gulp4

Сборщик проекта работает на 4 версии Gulp.
Есть код, ошибки в консоль не вылетают, все работает нормально, но папка dist не создается. Она создается только тогда, когда я убираю gulp.parallel('clean', 'sass', 'js'), но мне нужно выполнить эти таски до того, как создать папку dist и вложить в нее файлы. Как можно выполнить их перед выполнением самого таска? Так же пробовал использовать series, но все безуспешно.

```
gulp.task('build', gulp.parallel('clean', 'sass', 'js'), function () {

    var cssDist = gulp.src([
        'app/css/style.min.css',
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
    var fontsDist = gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*').pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));
    var jsDist = gulp.src(['app/js/**/*', '!app/js/common.js']).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
    var htmlDist = gulp.src(['app/*.html', '!app/template.html']).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    var imgDist = gulp.src('app/img/**/*')
        .pipe(cache(imagemin({
            interlaced: true,
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{
                removeViewBox: false
            }],
            use: [pngquant()]
        })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));

    return cssDist, fontsDist, jsDist, htmlDist, imgDist;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего после того, как вызывалась функция parallel, то анонимная функция просто не выполнялась. Пришлось создать еще один таск в которую я передавал series() - она отвечает за последовательное выполнение имеющихся тасков.

```
gulp.task('dest', function () {

    var cssDist = gulp.src([
        'app/css/style.min.css',
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
    var fontsDist = gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*').pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));
    var jsDist = gulp.src(['app/js/**/*', '!app/js/common.js']).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
    var htmlDist = gulp.src(['app/*.html', '!app/template.html']).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    var imgDist = gulp.src('app/img/**/*')
        .pipe(cache(imagemin({
            interlaced: true,
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{
                removeViewBox: false
            }],
            use: [pngquant()]
        })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));

    return cssDist, fontsDist, jsDist, htmlDist, imgDist;

});

gulp.task('build', gulp.series('clean', 'sass', 'js', 'dest'));
```